# Can I configure my soldiers perks for Multiplayer

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

At the squad creation screen for the multiplayer, I get to chose only from a few pre-set configuration, and can't choose what promotions they will get from the entire list like in the Single Player.

Is there another way to chose the perks, or maybe make some of my own "pre-set" configures for the soldiers.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this time you cannot edit the perks except by changing Type.
I think they do not have a points to perks rating, and just rated the soldier in his full.
As such, switching perks could unbalance an already badly balanced match up.